# How is the distance between the n-th term of a converging sequence and its' limit not zero?

Tags: limits

I'm confused as to what $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ really means. The reason for that is the following proof regarding the assertion that a converging sequence $(a_n)$ has one and only one limit.

This is the proof my professor gave:

Assume the opposite, that the convergent sequence $(a_n)$ has two limits:

$\displaylines{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=a}$ and $\displaylines{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=b}$.

We will now show that $a=b$.

From $\displaylines{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=a}$ we have that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists some $n_1(\epsilon)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>n_1(\epsilon)$ the following holds:

$|a_n-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$,

Similarly, from $\displaylines{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=b}$ we have that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists some $n_2(\epsilon)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>n_2(\epsilon)$ the following holds:

$|a_n-b|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Let $n_0=max\{n_1(\epsilon),n_2(\epsilon)\}$. Then, for all $n\geq n_0$ the following inequalities hold:

$|a_n-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|a_n-b|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Now, for all $n\geq n_0$ we have:

$|a-b|=|(a-a_n)+(a_n-b)|\leq|a-a_n|+|a_n-b|=|a_n-a|+|a_n-b|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$

Therefore, $|a-b|<\epsilon, \forall\epsilon>0\iff|a-b|=0\implies a=b$.

---

Now, if this is what the line above implies, then doesn't for instance $|a_n-a|<\epsilon, \forall \epsilon > 0$ also imply that $a_n=a$? Am I missing something?

Comment: The order of the quantifiers here is important: for **every** $\varepsilon>0$, **there exists** an $N\in\Bbb N$ **such that** $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$ for $n\geq N$. (The important part being that $\varepsilon>0$ is chosen first, *then* we find $N$ that works.)

Comment: I would pick one $\varepsilon$ for which $|a-b|>\varepsilon$. Then for this $\varepsilon$ you can find an $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$, $|a_n-a|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and $|b_n-b|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then the triangle inequality would say that $|a-b|<\varepsilon$

Comment: Rather than saying $\forall \epsilon > 0$ it should say for any $\epsilon>0$. One $\epsilon$ is picked then you go far enough along the sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ so that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ and $|b_n-b|<\epsilon$. Since a and b are fixed, if $|a-b|<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$ then a must be b.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of limit is: for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a positive integer $N$ $\textbf{dependent on $\epsilon$}$ such that $\mid a_n-a\mid < \epsilon$ for every $n \geqslant N$.

The result your professor uses at the very end is: if $a$ and $b$ are $\textbf{fixed}$ real numbers that satisfies $\mid a-b \mid < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$, then $a=b$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't get it.

Comment: A good way to understand the result is to write out the full proof of professor's result. Only then, you can see why it does not work in the definition of limit.